# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje sin perder la referencia?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Espero que me puedan orientar un poco.

Yo tenía una tabla, y por cada fila de dicha tabla un botón "eliminar" que funcionaba perfectamente, no obstante, no pedía confirmación antes de eliminar, así que intenté hacerlo.

El problema es que ahora me muestra el mensaje pero al darle a "aceptar" ya no me funciona.

La última celda de cada fila de la tabla tiene el botón "eliminar" (agrego esto a petición de Marcos):

```
<td> 
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeletion">
<button id="{{ 'delete-button-'.$loop->index }}" class="deleteFila btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-sid = "{{$celda['sid']}}" data-d = "{{$celda['d']}}" data-h = "{{$celda['h']}}" data-target="#exampleModal" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar" onclick=""><i class="material-icons mic">delete</i></button>
</span>
</td>
```

A continuación Ajax + JQuery

```
$(".deleteFila").click(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mostrarConfirmacion").modal("show");
  });
});
$("#eliminar").click(function() {

  $(".deleteFila").hide();
  var sid = $(this).data("sid");
  var d = $(this).data("d");
  var h = $(this).data("h");
  var token = 'ooFPicQiXvOQIwyaXbZxmsKd6TnyREitG7eKE64H';
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: "/tabla/" + sid + "/" + d + "/" + h,
    data: {
      _token: token,
      _sid: sid,
      _d: d,
      _h: h
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data['success'] == true)
        toastr.success('Eliminada correctamente', 'Fila');
      else
        toastr.error('Error al eliminar', 'Fila');
    }
  });
});

<div class="modal fade" id="mostrarConfirmacion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <i class="bi bi-trash3-fill fa-lg"><b> ¿ Estas seguro que desea eliminar ? </b></i><br><br>
        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
          <a style="margin-right: 20px" href="#" id="cancelar" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</a>
          <a href="#" id="eliminar" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Versión original que funciona sin preguntar:

```
   $(".deleteFila").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').hide();
        var sid = $(this).data("sid");
        var d = $(this).data("d");
        var h = $(this).data("h");
        var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        $.ajax(
        {
            method:'DELETE',
            url: "/tabla/"+sid+"/"+d+"/"+h,
            data: {_token: token, _sid:sid, _d:d, _h:h},
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data['success'] == true) 
                    toastr.success('Eliminada correctamente', 'Fila');
                else
                    toastr.error('Error al eliminar', 'Fila');
            }
        });
    });
```

¿De qué forma puedo hacer para no perder la referencia del botón al que se le ha hecho click para luego obtener todos los data-x?

Comment: Agrega un poco de la tabla HTML para que podamos reproducir tu problema sin tener que reescribirlo todo a mano, gracias

Comment: Hecho, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que antes `$(this)` hacía referencia al botón "eliminar" (*era el botón click-eado*), pero ahora hacer referencia al botón "aceptar" (*el botón del modal*).

#### Solución:

Podrías guardar la referencia al botón click-eado en una variable.

**Ejemplo:**

```
let $deleteBtn;

$(".deleteFila").click(function() {
  $deleteBtn = $(this); // <- Guardamos el btn click-eado
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mostrarConfirmacion").modal("show");
  });
});
$("#eliminar").click(function() {

  $deleteBtn.parents('tr').hide();
  
  var sid = $deleteBtn.data("sid"); // <- Obtenemos los datos del btn
  var d = $deleteBtn.data("d");
  var h = $deleteBtn.data("h");
  var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: "/tabla/" + sid + "/" + d + "/" + h,
    data: {
      _token: token,
      _sid: sid,
      _d: d,
      _h: h
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data['success'] == true)
        toastr.success('Eliminada correctamente', 'Fila');
      else
        toastr.error('Error al eliminar', 'Fila');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Voy a probarlo y te cuento. El hide pensé que ocultaba la fila luego de "darle a eliminar" y luego enviaba la petición al servidor

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y no me funciona, aunque sí hace la petición (devuelve código de error 403). Acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo el código original de jquery + ajax que sí funciona

Comment: @Carlos, al final funcionó? Te pregunto, porque la marcaste como "aceptada". Imagino que el problema era `{{ csrf_token() }}`

Comment: sí ese era el problema. Adicionalmente, la línea que comentábamos debería ser así:  $deleteBtn.parents('tr').hide(); (por si quieres cambiar ambas cosas de tú respuesta) para que quede funcionar para alguien que necesite lo mismo. Muchas gracias.